# How to select rows which values start and end with a specific value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

I have a pandas DataFrame, and I want to select rows which values start and end with a specific value. For example, in dataFrame `df`, I want to select rows that column `state` start and end with `1`. That is row `2 5 8 10`. and output two dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['a1',0,'low'],
        ['a1',0,'low'],
        ['a1',1,'high'],
        ['a1',1,'low'],
        ['a1',1,'low'],
        ['a1',1,'high'],
        ['a1',0,'low'],
        ['a1',0,'low'],
        ['a2',1,'high'],
        ['a2',1,'low'],
        ['a2',1,'low'],
        ['a2',0,'low'],
        ['a2',0,'low']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['id','state','type'])
df
```

out :

```
    id  state   type
0   a1     0    low
1   a1     0    low
2   a1     1    high
3   a1     1    low
4   a1     1    low
5   a1     1    high
6   a1     0    low
7   a1     0    low
8   a2     1    high
9   a2     1    low
10  a2     1    low
11  a2     0    low
12  a2     0    low
```

Finally, I want two dataframes, like this:

```
df1

    id  state   type  code
2   a1     1    high  start
8   a2     1    high  start

df2

    id  state   type  code
5   a1     1    high  end
10  a2     1    low   end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Boolean mask to select the rows you require:

```
m1 = df['state'].diff() == 1
m2 = df['state'].shift(-1).diff() == -1

res  = df[m1 | m2]

print(res)

    id  state  type
2   a1      1  high
5   a1      1  high
8   a2      1  high
10  a2      1   low
```

You can use a list comprehension to split into 2 dataframes:

```
df1, df2 = [res.iloc[i::2] for i in range(int(len(res.index)/2))]

print(df1, df2, sep='\n\n')

   id  state  type
2  a1      1  high
8  a2      1  high

    id  state  type
5   a1      1  high
10  a2      1   low
```